# How to split string for all fields in a Spark column and grab the length of the returned split string list?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm currently attempting the grab the amount of services a specific IP is running, and the services are in a `service` column, stored as a `StringType()` in a Spark DataFrame and are separated via commas. How do I go about splitting the string (split is based on commas) in each field, then aggregating the length of the returned list for each field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PySpark API:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("10.0.0.1", "session1,session2"), ("10.0.0.2", "session1,session3,session4")], ["ip", "session"])
>>> df.show(100, False)
+--------+--------------------------+
|ip      |session                   |
+--------+--------------------------+
|10.0.0.1|session1,session2         |
|10.0.0.2|session1,session3,session4|
+--------+--------------------------+

>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df = df.withColumn("count", size(split(col("session"), ",")))
>>> df.show(100, False)
+--------+--------------------------+-----+
|ip      |session                   |count|
+--------+--------------------------+-----+
|10.0.0.1|session1,session2         |2    |
|10.0.0.2|session1,session3,session4|3    |
+--------+--------------------------+-----+
```

You can learn more on PySpark API here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html